# Problem with the 0th harmonic of the Power Spectrum of an array

Tags: c++, opencv, fft, fingerprint

this is my first question!
The problem I'm trying to solve is: I'm creating a fingerprint pattern recognition program using OpenCV in C++. Following the paper I'm studying, I'm stuck on this part where it's said:

1. Compute the X-Signature array of values -> xSig[0, ..., w-1] (I've already done this part)
2. Compute the Power Spectrum, P[k], of the X-Signature where k=0 is the 0th harmonic and so on...

Now: the power spectrum I calculated is made by

```
Mat xSig = getxSig(); //ok
Mat fourier;          //Fourier ARRAY made with Mat for convenience
Mat PS;               //Power Spectrum, Mat for convenience
dft(xSig, fourier);   //
pow(abs(fourier), 2, PS);
```

The problem is that the 0th harmonic on the Power Spectrum is always a lot bigger than the other harmonics and that let me think there is a problem on what I'm doing, or on what I know are the harmonics themselves. The xSignature arrays that I'm dealing with are very small (max 20 values) and I thought that maybe this is the cause of having such an high 0th harmonic.

The power spectrum should be calculated with this formula: PS = |Fourier| ^2 as said in [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/power-spectrum) article,
[(formula extracted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p5js.png)

Here is an example of my calculated Power Spectrum from an xSignature: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmkU9.png)

And also, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkRGJ.png) is an example if I put PS[0] = 0 for testing. This shows a large peak in the second harmonic, which I'm not quite sure of the meaning but seems more appropriate than a higher 0th harmonic...

EDIT:

Thanks to Ext3h for the reply, I managed to do this:

```
Mat planes[] = { Mat_<float>(xSig), Mat::zeros(xSig.size(), CV_32F) };
Mat complexI;
merge(planes, 2, complexI);
dft(complexI, complexI);
split(complexI, planes);                   // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I), planes[1] = Im(DFT(I))
magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);// planes[0] = magnitude
Mat magI = planes[0];
```

which is actually copy pasted from the OpenCV guide and I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdzn2.png).
I enlarged the xSig array and also changed the way to compute the Power Spectrum.
As you can see the Power Spectrum figure is correct but still there is that "spike" on the 0th harmonic that i don't think should be there, but is an improvement.

Comment: The first number in a fourier series will be equal to the average of all the inputs. So it might be just that.

Comment: average maybe, or sum of them all. depends on how normalization is applied. 40 samples, mean 0.6 (it's top-heavy), I'd expect frequency 0 to be around 24, and the plot agrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abs` is the wrong operation. You need `split` followed by `magnitude` to get the norm of the *packed* complex numbers you got from `dft`.

Also your input vector may be far too short if you don't get any higher order harmonics.

Comment: Actually I saw this in [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d8/d01/tutorial_discrete_fourier_transform.html) but they was using an image to get the Power Spectrum so I didn't used it.